# How to get user's news feed via graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the user's news feed using the js api.  I'm not wanting the users feed, but the newsfeed they see if they click on the facebook logo in facebook.  This is the one that combines the user's feed with all their friends feeds.  Is this possible?
I would hate to have to do one query to get the feed from each of the users friends and then manually stitch them all together.  Is there another way?

Comment: I think I may be able to get something using FQL...  Will have to look into it

Comment: This seems like a likely candidate:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

Comment: The following query seems to return what I need.  It's missing people's names but I can live with that I suppose!

http://www.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT description_tags,description,message_tags,tagged_ids,xid,permalink,privacy,likes,comments,impressions,attachment,action_links,app_data,message,target_id,actor_id,attribution,filter_key,created_time,updated_time,source_id,app_id,viewer_id,post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() OR source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())

Comment: It's still far from perfect.  Hopefully someone has the answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this post is old, but I'm searching for it now, and since now Facebook has updated the API, there's a solution:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3

You'll have to have an extended permission for read_stream.

**Edit** |  There's a limitation as said on the page:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client
>   on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example,
>   Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In
>   addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this
>   permission.

Comment: It says This permission was removed after Graph API v2.3.