# Getting users news feed from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my portal, I have added user login and getting user profile information from facebook. 
My next target is to get the news feeds which appear on the home page of user. I refered to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122631/how-to-get-users-news-feed-via-graph-api)  but the accepted answer said it is not possible. Is it really not possible or there is a way to do it in present fb api?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer at [How to get user's news feed via graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122631/how-to-get-users-news-feed-via-graph-api) was over a year ago, whereas the other answer is 5 months ago. As documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home , the usage `https://graph.facebook.com/me/home` works, which I tested in the [API Graph Explorer Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and it worked. Let me know if it works for you :)